# WP Core Update Issue

Tags: errors, updates

Hi I am having some issues with my wordpress install.

I am getting 500 server error on my wp-admin page.

From my error logs I am getting some issues with Yoast SEO and compatibility. From sources it is recommended to update my wordpress version. (Running wp multisite)

I run `wp core update` but it is not working properly

`The address 127.0.0.1 is not in the database.
Updating to version 4.9.4 (en_US)...
Using cached file '/home/ubuntu/.wp-cli/cache/core/wordpress-4.9.4-no-content-
en_US.zip'...
Unpacking the update...
Error: Could not create directory.`

Could be file permissions?

Any help? Cheers

Comment: Given the error, I would as you suggest look at file/user permissions first. You are trying to update via wp-cli, have you tried the "old-fashioned" way by clicking the update button from wp-admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running v4.9.3, you will unfortunately have to do a manual upgrade to v4.9.4. According to [its release announcement](https://wordpress.org/news/2018/02/wordpress-4-9-4-maintenance-release/), v4.9.3 contained a bug that produces an error when you attempt to upgrade it from within the dashboard.

Comment: Thanks but I running 4.5.2 wanting to upgrade.